# How to split out string occurrences to an individual txt file?

Tags: python, split, readline

For example I've this txt files containing these lines,

```
chicken
chicken
duck
duck
duck
parrot
parrot
chicken
chicken
chicken
```

How can I read it line by line and split chicken (2 lines) to 1.txt, duck (3 lines) to 2.txt and parrot (2 lines) to 3.txt and the last chicken (3 lines) occurrence to a 4.txt?

I've figured out until here,

```
count = 0

with open("test.txt") as rl:
    for num, line in enumerate (rl, 1):
        s = list(line)
        if "chicken" in line:
            count += 1

            finaljoin = "".join(s)

            print(count)

            with open("chicken.txt", 'a+') as f:
                f.write(finaljoin)
```

But my solution above only grab the whole chicken (total 5) into one file. The actual plan was to grab the 1st two line to a txt file and the last two chicken line to another txt file. Because it is being split by another animals.

Comment: So obviously you only care about line with "chicken" in there, and only write to file named "chicken.txt". It is nothing like your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')

for ind, (_, g) in enumerate(groupby(data),1):
    with open('{}.txt'.format(ind), 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(g))
```

**Explanation:**

You can read about Itertools groupby here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby.

Groupby will return two elements, the key and the group. 
So if we want to loop through a groupby we would do something like this: `for key, group in groupby(object):` or `for k, g in groupby(object):`

Now in this case the keys will be `chicken, duck, parrot, chicken` and the groups  will be `['chicken', 'chicken'] , ['duck','duck... ...]`

However (now comes the part where I explain `ind, (_, g)`), to obtain an index as we loop we can use Python's enumerate function which will return an index and the iterator. Typically it looks like this: `for index, item in enumerate(list):` or `for ind, i in enumerate(list)`.

Now let's say we want to combine `enumerate` and `groupby`. Then we could do it like this: `for index, (key, group) in enumerate(groupby(object)):` or more compact: `for ind, (_, g) ...`. I use `_` in this case (and this is  Pythonic) to signal that I am not interested in the variable (the key in this case).

Comment: It works. Anyway I don't understand itertools concept much. But what "_" and "g" really does in your code?

Comment: @IzzatZainol Done.

Comment: Thanks @Anton vBR for your clear explanation.  I've marked the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
count = 0
with open("test.txt") as readFile:
    previous_line = ""
    archive_name = ""
    for line in readFile:
        if line != previous_line:
             previous_line = line
             count += 1
             archive_name = str(count)+".txt"
        with open(archive_name, 'a+') as f:  
            f.write(line)
```

That will save "chicken chicken" in 1.txt, "duck duck duck" in 2.txt, "parrot parrot" in 3.txt and "chicken chicken chicken" in 4.txt

Comment: I've tried your solution. But it split on every new lines.

Comment: it's working now. But do you know why it still create an additional final (unrelated) file with "chicken" only?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you haven't figured it out.  You have no splitting provision; all you've done is to search for "chicken", wherever it appears, and dump those reconstituted lines into a "chicken.txt" file.  You've made no provision for any other animal, and there's no attempt at logic to find those breaks.  Also, there's a lot of superfluous code in this, such as repeatedly opening your output file, and generating `num`, which is never used.

Draw out your basic logic on paper, if needed.  The critical step that you're missing is to check the previous animal against the current one.  This is something such as

```
previous = None
with open("test.txt") as zoo:
    for animal in zoo:
        if animal == previous:
            # Process same animal
        else:
            # Process new animal
        previous = animal   # remember animal for next iteration
```

Can you take it from there?
    for num, line in enumerate (rl, 1):

Comment: Thanks. I've the rough idea. Anyway the generating num i reserved for other purposed :)